# Draw a maze in Unity from 2D Arr

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multidimensional-array, 2d, game-development

I'm creating a game for a game jam and i make a static maze.
The problem is that the maze isn't made the same as in the maze.

```
{ 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
{ 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1},
{ 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1},
{ 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1},
{ 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1},
{ 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1},
{ 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1}
```

And isn't drawn right
[Labyrinth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17iHN.png)
I know that some of the walls are missing but i haven't inserted that code for now.

```
void CreateWalls() {
        for (int i = 0; i < gridSize; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < gridSize; j++) {
                if (grid[i, j] == 1) {
                    Vector3 position = new Vector3(i * wallSize, -j * wallSize, 1);
                    Quaternion rotation = transform.rotation;
                    GameObject createdWall = null;
 
                    bool hasTopWall = false;
                    bool hasLeftWall = false;
                    bool hasRightWall = false;
                    bool hasBottomWall = false;
 
                    Debug.Log("i: " + i + ", j: " + j);
 
 
                    if (i - 1 >= 0) {
                        if (grid[i - 1, j] == 1) {
                            hasLeftWall = true;
                        }
                    }
                    if (i + 1 < gridSize) {
                        if (grid[i + 1, j] == 1) {
                            hasRightWall = true;
                        }
                    }
 
                    if (j - 1 >= 0) {
                        if (grid[i, j - 1] == 1) {
                            hasTopWall = true;
                        }
                    }
 
                    if (j + 1 < gridSize) {
                        if (grid[i, j + 1] == 1) {
                            hasBottomWall = true;
                        }
                    }
 
                    if (hasTopWall && !hasLeftWall && !hasRightWall && hasBottomWall) { // vertical
                        createdWall = Instantiate(verticalWallPrefab, position, rotation);
 
                    } else if (!hasTopWall && hasLeftWall && hasRightWall && !hasBottomWall) { // horizontal
                        createdWall = Instantiate(horizontalWallPrefab, position, rotation);
 
                    } else if (hasTopWall && hasLeftWall && hasRightWall && !hasBottomWall) { // top - left - right
                        createdWall = Instantiate(threeWayWallTopLeftRightPrefab, position, rotation);
 
                    } else if (!hasTopWall && hasLeftWall && hasRightWall && hasBottomWall) { // bottom - left - right
                        createdWall = Instantiate(threeWayWallBottomLeftRightPrefab, position, rotation);
 
                    } else if (hasTopWall && hasLeftWall && hasRightWall && !hasBottomWall) { // top - left - bottom
                        createdWall = Instantiate(threeWayWallBottomLeftRightPrefab, position, rotation);
 
                    } else if (hasTopWall && !hasLeftWall && hasRightWall && hasBottomWall) { // top - right - bottom
                        createdWall = Instantiate(threeWayWallTopBottomRightPrefab, position, rotation);
 
                    } else if (hasTopWall && hasLeftWall && hasRightWall && hasBottomWall) { // four way
                        createdWall = Instantiate(fourWayWall, position, rotation);
 
                    } else if (hasTopWall && hasLeftWall && !hasRightWall && !hasBottomWall) {
                        createdWall = Instantiate(cornerLeftBottomTop, position, rotation);
 
                    } else if (hasTopWall && !hasLeftWall && hasRightWall && !hasBottomWall) {
                        createdWall = Instantiate(cornerRightBottomTop, position, rotation);
 
                    } else if (!hasTopWall && !hasLeftWall && hasRightWall && hasBottomWall) {
                        createdWall = Instantiate(cornerTopRightBottom, position, rotation);
 
                    } else if (!hasTopWall && hasLeftWall && !hasRightWall && hasBottomWall) {
                        createdWall = Instantiate(cornerTopLeftBottom, position, rotation);
                    }
 
                    if(createdWall != null) {
                        createdWall.transform.parent = GameObject.Find("WallHolder").transform;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

How do i flip the maze like i want it to?
And do you have a better way to get all the different walls (i need different walls because its a 2.5D Top Down game

I already tried to negate the y and also x coordinates
And I tried to change the rotation during the creation

Comment: Looks like you simply want to flip the usage of `i` and `j` .. and rather make it `i` -> Y axis and `j` -> X axis

Comment: And instead of using different walls shapes .. wouldn't it be actually enough to use simple cubes? 1 -> place cube, 0 -> do not place cube

Comment: You could also simplify a bit using e.g. `var hasLeftWall = i >= 1 && grid[i - 1, j] == 1;` etc .. though in general it might be even easier to just find the ones which are `==0` and for those check whether it is a "tunnel" or a corner and only spawn the walls that are actually needed ... Otherwise what if there is a solid 9 bock of  `1` ?

Comment: That i flipped i and j really worked thanks
No it wouldn't because I make a 2.5D game and the walls don't look the same

Comment: How should it work with playing the walls (which walls are needed) when i only searching for the `0`-s

Comment: What I meant is you only search the `0` .. then according to what is next to them you spawn a wall or not .. basically the same you already do but coming more from the path rather than the wall perspective.

Comment: What I meant about the simple cubes - for each grid cell you have potentially 4 walls around it .. so theoretically you could just have those 4 walls around each square but simply disable them if you are a `0` and there is a `0` next to you in a certain direction -> all `0`s will be "connected" by **not** having a wall between them. This way you wouldn't need different shapes at all

Comment: My walls have a different shape -> horizontal walls are 10 and 3 and the vertical 3 and 10
(x, y - width)

Comment: Exactly.. but what hinders you from having 4 potential walls - all with 3x10 dimensions just rotated differently - around each cell of your grid, then you just disable according ones -> you have the wall shape you wanted. Of course there also speaks nothing against your different shapes .. up to you, it was just a different idea which would be way easier to handle

Comment: oh well, i don't have the time to change now but i understand what you mean